# java.lang.LinkageError on OSGi application using SLF4J+Logback

Tags: java, maven, osgi, slf4j, logback

I’ve replaced JUL logging with SLF4J+Logback on a Java (1.8) application that is an OSGi bundle. However, after the replacement, I can longer get it to run (see the error below). I'm using the Maven Bundle plugin (BND), but am no expert in OSGi.

```
14:21:09.846 [FelixStartLevel] ERROR o.p.o.framework.FrameworkSlf4jLogger - Error starting file:/myapp/target/distribution/bundles/myapp.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle myapp [10].
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2204) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304) [org.apache.felix.main-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:336) ~[slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:1.7.12]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:284) ~[slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:1.7.12]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:305) ~[slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:1.7.12]
    at org.koolapi.ServiceLoaderModule.<clinit>(ServiceLoaderModule.java:35) ~[koolapi-3.7.4.jar:3.7.4.20150518-0134]
    at org.koolapi.apibinding.Manager.createInjector(Manager.java:99) ~[koolapi-3.7.4.jar:3.7.4.20150518-0134]
    at org.koolapi.apibinding.Manager.instatiateDocumentManager(Manager.java:197) ~[koolapi-3.7.4.jar:3.7.4.20150518-0134]
    at org.koolapi.apibinding.Manager.createDocumentManager(Manager.java:38) ~[koolapi-3.7.4.jar:3.7.4.20150518-0134]
    at org.myapp.app.Activator.loadConfiguration(Activator.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.myapp.app.Activator.start(Activator.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.4.1.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

About the dependencies: myapp depends on parent-app, which depends on slf4j-api v1.7.12, guava v18, logback-core and logback-classic v1.1.3. So I don't explicitly set these dependencies in myapp's pom.xml. myapp has one other key dependency, which is koolapi; this OSGi bundle contains slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar in its /lib/ folder, but there's no Export-Package directive in its manifest.

Overall I checked the manifests of all bundles (felix, guava, logback-core, logback-classic, slf4j-api, koolapi, parent-app) to see who is using/exporting slf4j, and only logback-classic.jar explicitly exports org.slf4j.impl;version=1.7.7.

Does anyone have any idea or advice on how to solve the conflict?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks, 
Joel

Answer (score 3):

The error means that you have created a situation where one classloader has visibility of the type `ILoggerFactory` coming from multiple defining classloaders. This is not legal in Java, hence the `LinkageError`.

It'd difficult to diagnose for sure without full bundle contents and manifests, but the cause is *probably* the copy of `slf4j-api` inside `koolapi` bundle. Embedding libraries like this okay *unless* the types leak out via the signatures of methods on the exported types. Because of this leakage, your app bundle is exposed to multiple copies of the `ILoggerFactory` type.

The fix should be relatively simple: remove `slf4j-api.jar` from inside `koolapi` and make `koolapi` import the package as a normal dependency.